# injecting a javascript code into a jpg image and execute the code when uploaded with c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have recently been working in a security project and i have a task to demonstrate that javascript code injection can be done when the user upload an malicious image and this is a lack of security if it's not handled .
what i did is i used `EXIFeditor` to inject the image with some javascript code and than i uploaded the image into the browser using this code

```
 protected void Upload_File(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var postedFile = Upload_fu.PostedFile;
    string fileName=new FileInfo(postedFile.FileName).Name;
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + fileName);
    postedFile.SaveAs(path);
    Success_msg.Text = "successfully saved";
    img_sr.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + fileName;
}
```

Where `img_sr` is an `<asp:Image` and `Upload_fu` is `<asp:UploadFile` 
the javascript code i've injected is a simple `alert("Hello world")`
the problem is the code is not being executed. can u guys tell me how should i make it execute and can u show me some link that can give me a hint or something to make that happen .I tried it on firefox 21 and IE 9,I've posted my question in Infomation Security but no one answer ,I hope you guys can help .thank u

Comment: How do you set the javascript alert in image description? Does the editor you have used allows you to do the same or any other method?

Comment: the software i used can change a tag inside the image and put a value (wish is here the javascript code) check out this link :http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/

Answer (score 2):

Browser will not automatically execute javascript from the image metadata. Your expectations are wrong. This has nothing to do with C# or .NET at all. What you want to do is to read out the javascript from the image metadata ( by using javascript ) and then execute that javascript that you read out by calling eval or doing something similar.

You can find similar example here: http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/02/new-iframe-injections-leverage-png-image-metadata.html

Comment: but in real case scenarios a normal developer will only get the uploaded image path and show it to the client .

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say?

Comment: i mean a normal developer ( a developer with a bit of knowledge ) will not check the metadata of the image and he will do what i did , right ?,what i am trying to say is the meta data in normal behavior will not be checked and a simple image upload will be done , so i guess your answer should be done when a security issue is taken under control ,not in a normal way,and this is not what i am looking for ,what i want is to execute the code without even knowing that a code is being injected

Comment: what you are looking for is not possible